# Getting Unhandled DataStoreubEvent: outboxMutationFailed

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

I am trying to save data into DataStore Amplify Studio but I keep getting this error. I get this error whenever I save contactMobile. The rest like aboutMe stores fine.

```
OutboxMutationFailedEvent{errorType=UNKNOWN, operation=UPDATE, modelName=Trainers, model=SerializedModel{id='0e871e26-a5de-44ba-ac5c-607bbc79acbe', serializedData={contactMobile=123456789, aboutMe=qq}}
```

Here is my [contactMobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sXFEp.jpg) which I have set the type to AWSPhone and I save the data with TextEditingController.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. I get this error because the data I stored is in the wrong format. When I put AWSPhone, it should be in the correct format with country code, for e.g, "+60161234567".

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).